# Display an “Invalid Index Number” message if the user enters an index number that doesn’t exist in the questions list

Tags: python, list

I am new to the programming.Please apologise for any mistakes in writing as I am not used to stackoverflow. 
I want to know how to display an "Invalid index Number" message if the user enters an invalid index number which doesn't exists in the list.
Here is code and the function which gets called to prompt user for an input(integer from 0 to n) which will display the questions and answers if found in the list.

```
def inputInt(prompt):
choice=raw_input(prompt)
return choice

if choice=="v":
        if not questions:
            print "No Questions Saved"
        else:
            print "Which Question number do you want to view?"
            selectedc=inputInt(">")    
            print questions[selectedc]['question']
            print questions[selectedc]['answer']+"(Correct)"
            print questions[selectedc]['wrong1']+"(Incorrect)"
            print questions[selectedc]['wrong2']+"(Incorrect)"
            print questions[selectedc]['wrong3']+"(Incorrect)"
```

I am writing a program for adding and viewing questions and their answers. I made a list "questions". Each of items in a list is a dictionary consisting of 5 items which have keys of “question”, “answer”, “wrong1”, “wrong2” and “wrong3”.

Please tell me the code or the way by which I can display a Message on console if that particular index in list is not there.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Could you indent your code correctly?

Comment: This is quite a basic question, not really what Stack Overflow is for. Look up docs and tutorials to learn more about Python and you'll find plenty of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check if the index is valid. An easy way to do this would be to check if the index is `>=0` or `< len(list_name)`

e.g.:

```
if selectedc >= 0 and selectedc < len(questions):
    print(questions[selectedc]['question'])
    ...
else:
    print('Invalid index number')
```

This works for lists (which you said `questions` was), whereas KingRadical's answer works if you want to do something similar for your dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

in Python you can check most collection types if they contain a value using the `in` operator, and is an efficient operation for hashed collection types such as dicts and sets.

Given your example:

```
selectedc = inputInt(">")
if selectedc in questions:
    print(questions[selectedc]['question']
    ...

else:
    print("Question not found")
    ...
```

should do it, if I understood the question.